# Setting up Spinner filled with data without any reference to Android resources

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

Busy creating an interface with spinner (dropdown) programmatically. To populate with data you need an (Array)Adapter. What I don't understand is why you need a reference to an Android resource at all, like "android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item". Is it possible to populate the Spinner with webservice data, without any reference to such an Android resource? If not, why not and how should this resource look like, in an environment without layout's. If it is possible, please show me how, since google is no help here (to me).

Thanks in advance!

Update:

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this.getActivity());
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), whatComesHere, list);
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
tableRow.addView(spinner);
```

**The questions is: what to substitute for 'whatComesHere'?**

thanks in advance.

Update-2

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_admin_platform"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
android:entries="@array/my_spinner" />
```

Comment: You don't need array resources. I personally fill a Spinner reading the values from a db, so I guess you can do the same through a WebService, too.

Comment: Yes, but how? Do you use an adapter and if yes, what do you fill in the 2nd parameter 'resource': public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, List<T> objects)

Comment: It is not necessary to fill the adapter with resources.you can dynamically fill data to adapter.

Comment: Yes, but how?! Please see my updated question with code example.

Comment: I have to make an answer, since comments don't allow line breaks.

Comment: If you study the API [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int)) you see that ALL constructors have a resource as 2nd parameter. So, how to circumvent this?

Comment: The spinner needs a resource to know how to display the data. There is the view that shows the spinner item when is selected and there is the view that is used for the dropdown items. You need those 2 in order to display your data. It's possible to create your own but you need them.

Comment: See my update-2. So are you saying that I have to have the above xml in a resource file and that there is no way to avoid xml altogether and just set up de Spinner pure in code? And that I need an Adapter that refers to @array/my_spinner?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
 private void FillCitySnipper() {
ArrayList<MyCity> ListOfCity=db.LoadMyCity();
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (ListOfCity.size() > 0) {
                Spinner spinner = (Spinner) this
                        .findViewById(R.id.spnr_Cityname);
                ArrayAdapter<MyCity> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyCity>(
                        this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        ListOfCity);
                spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
            }
    }
```