# How to write an Android app without xml

Tags: android, xml, resources

In the wake of a [question asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21759117/setting-up-spinner-filled-with-data-without-any-reference-to-android-resources), I am still attempting to write to little app without any xml whatsoever. Here is my attempt (origin code [here](http://androidexample.com/Spinner_Basics_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=82&aaid=105)), that works, but fails because of "Resources$NotFoundException" if the two commented out lines replace the two lines before them:

```
public class SpinnerExample extends Activity {

    private Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        setContentView(linearLayout);

        spinner = new Spinner(this);
        linearLayout.addView(spinner);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Android");
        list.add("Java");
        list.add("Spinner Data");
        list.add("Spinner Adapter");
        list.add("Spinner Example");

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
        //ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 0x7f030012, list);

        CheckedTextView checkedTextView = new CheckedTextView(this);
        checkedTextView.setId(0x7f030022);  // arbitrary value

        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.spinner_dropdown);
        //dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(0x7f030012);

        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}

    // Add spinner data

    public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection(){
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
    }
}
```

The xml resources refer to:

android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```

android.R.layout.spinner_dropdown:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```

Can somebody explain to may why this exception occurs and how to prevent it and have an app without xml?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**: added the suggestion of 323go and made this class:

```
public class MyArrayAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {

    List<T> list;

    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        list = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        CheckedTextView tv = new CheckedTextView( this.getContext() );
        tv.setText( "This is item " + position );
        return tv;
    }
}
```

...and obviously replacede ArrayAdapter with MyArrayAdapter in the original code. The result is that the spinner is shown with "This is item 0", but still gives the original exception is you tap on the spinner.

**UPDATE-2**

The question is half solved, I can get rid of the first xml reference with this ArrayAdapter:

```
public class MyArrayAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {

    List<T> list;

    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        list = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        CheckedTextView tv = new CheckedTextView( this.getContext() );
        tv.setText(list.get(position).toString());
        return tv;
    }
}
```

Now the code in SpinnerExample can be modified like this:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);

MyArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new MyArrayAdapter<String>(this, textView.getId(), list);
```

New is that I learned that Android attributes an id to a widget created in code as well. So no need for this:

textView.setId(0x7f030012); // arbitrary int

Comment: The bigger question would be why would you write an Android app without XML.

Comment: Because I need to set up a flexible, configurable GUI from data coming from a webservice, that's why.

Comment: `0x7f030012` where did these "magic" numbers come from and what are you trying to do with them in the commented lines?

Comment: @Simon: I think he opened R.java

Comment: I just added to the code that these values are arbitrary. They could have been "1" and "2". Artoo Detoo: you are correct.

Comment: @ArtooDetoo  I think you're right, in which case the question is how to use the constructors for adapters and views in code?

Comment: Those IDs are **Only** used when using XML.  The compiler assigns each view in XML layouts a resource ID and adds it to R.java as a static field so that your code can reference it via the friendly name (the id).  In code, you do not do this.  You create an instance of a view and pass the parent view to it's constructor.

Comment: Or something very dangerous might occur.

Comment: "Because I need to set up a flexible, configurable GUI from data coming from a webservice, that's why" -- that does not preclude the use of layout XML resources.

Comment: Simon, I see. So the setId() is not going to work. But how then can I get this spinner working without xml? I can get TextEdit and EditText working without xml. The problem is how to get the adapter working without xml. How can I replace the resource-id with a reference to the in code constructed TextView and CheckedTextView?

Comment: CommonsWare, you are right. Nevertheless I would like to have the question answered. See it as a sport ;)

Comment: When you create view in code, Android assigns an ID to it.  You can call `getId()`.  You could also set it, but  then you are responsible for managing it, ensuring uniqueness within a view tree etc.  In any case, this is not usually needed since you create a reference to the new view, and access it through that.  `TextView myTexView = new TextView(this, parentContainer)` and later, `myTextView.setText("Hello world");`

Comment: Right, @Simon -- additionally, he's passing the id of a view to `setDropDownViewResource`, where it should really be a layout to be inflated (and new views created from it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going about it the wrong way. XML or not, you still need IDs if you want to access elements by ID. Hardcoding IDs is not a good idea, and there's nothing wrong using the `android.R.id...` constants.

Further, the reason why your code fails is that `setDropDownViewResource()` expects the id of a *layout*, not of an actual *view*. A layout will tell Android what views to create through the `LayoutInflater`. If your code worked, then the same view would be referenced by id for each of the `Spinner` rows.

If you want to completely handle the UI creation yourself, you'll need to override the `ArrayAdapter` so that `getView` returns the view for each element. It might be easier, however, to just use the `android.R` layouts, unless you need something different.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView tv = new TextView( context, parent );
    tv.setText( "This is item " + position );
    return tv;
}
```

Comment: OK, than no hardcoding IDs, fine with me. But how can I setup an adapter, necessary for populating the spinner, without xml? That was the original question. You say: "override the adapter with getView for each element". How would this getView look like? Should ik return a TextView? CheckedTextView

Comment: It depends on what you want to have in there. If it's a CheckedTextView, return that, if it's the TextView, return that.

Comment: 32390, almost there, see my updated original text. I can now use "MyArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new MyArrayAdapter<String>(this, 0x7f030012, list);" and see the original list of 5 entries, with "This is item 0" on top and no crash.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any traces of your self-generated ids in the instantiation of `MyArrayAdapter` or `setDropDownView`.

Comment: How? All 6 constructors of ArrayAdapter have an (resource) int as 2nd parameter.

Comment: Use the `android.R.layout` as the default.

Comment: See my update-2. The question was 'half answered' in that I got rid of one dependency of xml. Thanks everybody.